# .htaccess to URL rewrite AND force https

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, .htaccess, https, rewrite

site: example.com

Joomla subdirectory: example.com/joomla

**I want the Joomla install at example.com/joomla to be (or appear to be) the root of the site**, i.e. people visiting example.com are redirected to example.com/joompla/index.php but still see example.com in the URL bar. **I also want to use this opportunity for force all incoming connections to use HTTPS**. I have been able to do one or the other using scripts I have found online but not both with consistency.

Here is what I have so far for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrites all URLS without joomla in them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/joomla/

# Rewrites all URLS with example in them
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /joomla
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [L]

# This works SOME of the time to redirect to https
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

# If a request tries to access /joomla directly, redirect it to its secured canonical version
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} joomla/
RewriteRule ^joomla/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to work some of the time in Chrome, redirecting to the Joomla installation and switching to https, but sometimes I need to force a hard reload repeatedly to get there. It NEVER works in Firefox, staying on http on the rare occasion that it loads the site at all.

I am very new to .htaccess and I am not sure I have developed the most elegant or comprehensive solution to the above problem. I have seen other examples online using `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` or `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` together with various `RewriteRule` commands but I am not sure how to to combine these commands with the existing URL rewriting conditions and as a result I am sure I am missing the fringe scenarios.

Can somebody with more experience guide me through this? It would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying variations of scripts found online for a few days now but haven't quite found the magic words.

Comment: Presumably you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/joomla` subdirectory that routes the request through Joomla? Your last directive redirects to plain `HTTP`? There is no HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the code you posted? Is Joomla itself correctly configured regarding the URL structure (ie no `/joomla`)? The Joomla Stack might be a better fit for this?

Comment: I don't have another .htaccess in the /joomla subdirectory. Can you explain "routes through Joomla"? I can go ahead add https to the final command but that will only handle if somebody types example.com/joomla into the URL bar. How can I send the more common references to example.com to https on joomla?

Comment: "I don't have another .htaccess in the /joomla subdirectory. Can you explain "routes through Joomla"?" - If you don't then `index.php` is presumably present in your URLs? Joomla comes with a `.htaccess` file by default - something like this: https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Comment: I removed that file because it resulted in 500 errors when trying to access anything on Joomla site. I am not sure why--the default parameters must conflict with the .htaccess file I put in the main web root--but I think I will have to put it back eventually because I believe I need it to develop a SEF URL strategy?

Comment: Yes, it is required for SEF URLs. But... how you implement this is different if you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/joomla` subdirectory vs without. You should examine your server error log to get the details of any 500 error. You will likely need to make a slight change to the default `.htaccess` file if it is located in a subdirectory (but that depends on the directives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes regarding your existing directives:

> RewriteBase /

Whilst you've defined the `RewriteBase`, it is not being used in any of your directives. The `RewriteBase` only applies to relative path *substitutions* (you've explicitly used a root-relative URL-path in the relevant directives).

> ```
> # Rewrites all URLS with example in them
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.
> ```

Do you *need* to check the requested hostname? Unless you are hosting multiple domains (or subdomains) that you do not want to apply this rule to then this *condition* is superfluous.

> ```
> # This works SOME of the time to redirect to https
> Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
> ```

This *never* triggers a "redirect", so I'm not sure what you are seeing in the network traffic?

(In fact, there is nothing in the code you posted that would trigger a "redirect" from HTTP to HTTPS.)

This HTTP response header causes the browser to automatically "upgrade" any requests for *linked resources* (CSS, JS, images, external resources, etc.) from the initial HTML (page) response that would otherwise be over HTTP (eg. because the actual URL contains `http://...`) to be over HTTPS. No actual "redirect" occurs. And nothing happens with the initial HTML response that might have been over plain HTTP.

This header is not strictly necessary if you have implemented a site-wide HTTP to HTTPS redirect and all your linked resources are already HTTPS or use a root-relative (or protocol-relative) URL. But it does provide a good safety net. Note, however, that any linked resources that do not support HTTPS will simply break - no browser warning to the user. Without this header then the user potentially receives a browser "mixed content" warning (and the linked resource fails).

> ```
> # If a request tries to access /joomla directly, redirect it to its secured canonical version
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} joomla/
> RewriteRule ^joomla/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteCond` directive (used to prevent a redirect-loop under "normal conditions") matches `joomla/` anywhere in the requested URL, even in the query string - which is incorrect and could potentially result in incorrect redirects if `joomla/` should appear elsewhere in the URL-path or even the query string. For instance, this would result in a redirect-loop if I simply appended `?joomla/` to the end of any URL.

This "redirect" should go *before* the internal rewrites. In general, "redirects" should go before "rewrites" to avoid redirecting a rewritten URL and exposing the rewritten URL to your users.

As noted in comments, this redirect is to HTTP - the opposite of what you are trying to do (and will result in a small redirect-chain when implementing an HTTP to HTTPS redirect).

#### A few assumptions:

- The SSL cert is installed directly on the application server, ie. no Cloudflare (Flexible-SSL) or other front-end proxy that manages the SSL.
- You are no using any other subdomains. Just `www`.
- The canonical hostname is non-www, ie. `example.com` (from the redirect in your question).
- You are not implementing HSTS at this time, so you can redirect to HTTPS and the canonical hostname (ie. `example.com`) in a single redirect.
- Joomla itself has already been configured to omit the `/joomla` subdirectory from the URLs. `/joomla` is not present on any internal links, including links to static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.)
- You are not serving any files from the document root. *Everything* is to go to the `/joomla` subdirectory.

### Scenario #1 - A single `.htaccess` file in the document root.

(As stated in comments.)

In this scenario, there is no "Joomla" `.htaccess` file in the installation subdirectory (`/joomla`) in which to route your URLs to the Joomla front-controller (ie. `index.php`). In which case, `index.php` must be present in the URL and you cannot use Joomla's "SEF" URLs.

The root `/.htaccess` file would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /joomla

# If a request tries to access /joomla directly, redirect it to its secured canonical 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/joomla
RewriteRule ^joomla(?:$|/(.*)) https://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]

# Canonicalise the hostname - ie. www to non-www and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect remaining requests from HTTP to HTTPS
# The hostname must already be canonical at this point
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Rewrite everything to the /joomla subdirectory
# Uses the value defined in the RewriteBase directive above
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Ensure that any linked resources are requested over HTTPS
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Note that I've used 302 (temporary) redirects here for testing purposes. Always test first with 302 redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) once it has been confirmed to work OK. 301s are persistently cached by the browser so can make testing problematic.

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is used to ensure we only rewrite direct requests and not rewritten requests, in much the same way `THE_REQUEST` is used in the first rule. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP response status) after the first successful rewrite. The directive `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]` may look a bit odd at first (it looks like it rewrites to itself), however, the `RewriteBase` is prefixed to the resulting substitution, so it actually rewrites to `/joomla/<url>`.

### Scenario #2 - Two `.htaccess` files: document root and subdirectory

The `.htaccess` file in the `/joomla` subdirectory would be the reasonably standard `.htaccess` file that comes with Joomla. This routes all requests to the Joomla front-controller (ie. `index.php`) and enables the use of Joomla's "SEF" URLs (ie. you do not need to explicitly include `index.php` in the URL).

The root `/.htaccess` file would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /joomla

# Canonicalise the hostname - ie. www to non-www and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Redirect remaining requests from HTTP to HTTPS
# The hostname must already be canonical at this point
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Rewrite everything to the /joomla subdirectory
# Uses the value defined in the RewriteBase directive above
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Ensure that any linked resources are requested over HTTPS
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Note the redirect to remove the `/joomla` subdirectory from the URL has been removed and needs to go in the `/joomla/.htaccess` file. (It would be entirely superfluous if left here.)

You do not need the check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var this time since the `/joomla/.htaccess` will *catch* the request after it has been rewritten. (Assuming mod_rewrite inheritance has not been enabled.)

The `Header` directive could be moved to the `/joomla/.htaccess` if you wanted to - this is optional as it will be "inherited" anyway.

Then, the `/joomla/.htaccess` file would contain something like the following:

```
# JOOMLA: Set Options here

RewriteEngine on

# If a request tries to access here directly then redirect back to root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]

# JOOMLA: Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# :

# Leave the RewriteBase directive commented out - it's not required
#RewriteBase /joomla

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

The `/joomla/.htaccess` file is loosely based on [the code on the Joomla website](https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess), however, I've omitted the common elements/comments and changed the "SEF Section" to be relevant for the subdirectory. (Joomla also use a less efficient regex `.*` instead of simply `^`.)

Comment: This is hugely helpful not just for the site but understanding the specifics of htaccess. Thank you so much!